# Refresh List on Second Fragment from fourth fragment

Tags: java, android

Please go through below of to understand the problem.
1. I have 4 fragments on mainActivity.
2. On second fragment "DEF" has a list. (fragment state preserved).
3. On button click from second fragment "DEF", moves to third fragment "GHI".
4. On button click from third fragment "GHI", moves to fourth fragment "XYZ".
5. After work done on "XYZ", second fragment "DEF" comes front.
6. i have to refresh the list on second fragment "DEF" without removing the fragment.
How can i achieve this?

I have already tried interface. Since it is one to one, it is useless in my case.

Expected-Result: A list on second fragment "DEF" should gets refreshed after i have done working on fourth fragment "XYZ".

Comment: So you just need a way so that your fragments can communicate with each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with interface and a function.

The interface can be used to notify the work is done. Method to refresh the list.

In your case the fourth fragment can supply a value to MainActivity through interface. From that method you can easily call a method in Second fragment using its object. Inside the method you can refresh the list.

Comment: i am not calling my fourth fragment from activity / from second fragment directly. How am i supposed to call interface in an activity?

Comment: check out this link https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating it explains how to communicate between fragments.

Comment: it is one-to-one activity-fragment connectivity. It has no use for me. My problem is to refresh the second fragment from fourth fragment.